# Using files in Check test cases

Tags: c, file, check-framework

I need to use a file for one of my tests written using [Check](http://check.sourceforge.net/). I initially hardcoded the path, which worked fine. However, this didn't work when the code is built outside of the source directory. I came up with the following solution which somewhat works. (I then prefix pathnames with `TESTS_DIR`)

```
# Set correct directory for test files
AS_IF([test "x$srcdir" = x.],
      [TESTS_DIR=""],
      [TESTS_DIR="$srcdir/tests/"])
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([TESTS_DIR], ["$TESTS_DIR"], [directory for test files])
```

Unfortunately, this fails again for `make distcheck`. I could post specific path layouts and structures, but I'm wondering if there's an "easy" way to refer to files in the source directory in all these cases. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I've tried to use absolute paths, but it seems `$abs_top_srcdir` isn't set when I tried to update the define in `configure.ac`. Any thoughts as to why that is would be appreciated.

Comment: How? As you can see, I have tried to come up with a relative path which works in all scenarios. No dice. In fact, I'd probably be happier with an absolute path. If the user has to reconfigure when moving directories around, it's not the end of the world. But a proper solution using relative paths would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the problem was that `$top_srcdir` is not set at configure time. Instead, I added `-DTESTS_DIR="\"$(top_srcdir)/tests/\""` to `AM_CFLAGS` in my tests `Makefile.am` and also added all directories containing test files to `EXTRA_DIST`.